# Edge triggered register write

Tags: mips, clock, cpu-registers, processor

I am reading a book about MIPS. In that book I found the following figure where D represents data, Clk is the clock. Could somebody explain me this as I am not from Electrical Engineering background (I am from Computer Engineering background). What are the crosses in the data (in figure)?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this is not explained earlier in the book?

Answer (score 1):

It is important that flipflops provide a stable output on the clock signal. This is why they have to be stable during the time shortly before the clock signal until the time shorty after the clock signal. In your graph, the lines represent the value of your data, so wether your wire is 1 or 0. As you can see in the graph, on the rising clock edge the value is either 1 or 0, but there is no cross, so it cannot change during that time.

On the clock signal, the value gets passed on to Q, so Q can change, indicated by the cross. Then Q will carry this value as input to a logic and the output of that logic will be passed to D. This is why the value of Q changes before the value of D - it takes time to pass the signal through the logic. After that we want to store the value of D in a fliplop again, which is why the value has to become stable again and connot Change until after the clock Signal. The whole Thing starts over again.

Hope this helps! ;)